# case_when with multiple conditions on large grouped data.frame is slow. How to speed it up?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my first question, so sorry for possible mistakes and please do not hesitate to give feedback on the way I asked it!
I have a quite large dataset (1 million rows), with around 70.000 Instruments (=firms), and on average around 15 years (long format). I want to create a new variable using case_when with multiple conditions, grouped over each instrument. However, the run time is several hours. I feel like my code is inefficient and would like to learn how to speed it up. I hope the R hive mind can help and I hope I will be able to contribute on here in the near future.
I guess the only package required here is tidyverse (or dplyr)

1. DATA

This is a sample of the required data (10 rows)

```
test <- tibble::tibble(
  Year = seq(1998, 2007, by = 1),
  Instrument = rep("4295196544", 10L),
  p_pbt_situation = rep(
    c(
      "payouts_rise_more_than_profits_rise", "payouts_fall_less_than_profits_fall",
      "no current payout", "rising_payout_falling_profit"
    ),
    c(1L, 2L, 6L, 1L)
  ),
  has_ever_payout = rep(1, 10L),
  has_had_payout = rep(1, 10L),
)
```

2. Code using case_when

This code works, but for 100 rows it takes approx 3 seconds, so for the full dataset it would take approx
8 hours and 20min

```
test %>% group_by(Instrument) %>% 
    mutate(
        Ratchet_occurrence = 
case_when(
     sum(p_pbt_situation == "rising_payout_falling_profit", na.rm=TRUE) == 0 & has_ever_payout==1 ~"never",
     sum(p_pbt_situation == "rising_payout_falling_profit", na.rm=TRUE) == 1 ~"once",
     sum(p_pbt_situation == "rising_payout_falling_profit", na.rm=TRUE) == 2 ~ "twice",
     sum(p_pbt_situation == "rising_payout_falling_profit", na.rm=TRUE) >2 & sum(p_pbt_situation == "rising_payout_falling_profit", na.rm=TRUE) < 5   ~ "three or four",
     sum(p_pbt_situation == "rising_payout_falling_profit", na.rm=TRUE) >4 & sum(p_pbt_situation == "rising_payout_falling_profit", na.rm=TRUE) < 7   ~ "five or six",
     sum(p_pbt_situation == "rising_payout_falling_profit", na.rm=TRUE) >6   ~ "seven or more",
     has_ever_payout == 0 ~ "no payout",
     TRUE ~ NA_character_
        )) %>% ungroup()
```

Thank you in advance and kind regards

Comment: In addition to the code optimization suggested by @DrEspresso, `dplyr_1.1.0` had some code regressions with `case_when` (and `if_else`, I think) wrt performance. While I doubt that issue causes slowdown that would be much larger than the inefficiency of running the identical `sum(.)` expression eight times, it is still a factor. If you're running `dplyr_1.1.0`, I suggest you upgrade (current version is `1.1.2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you first create a new column with the sum:

```
library(dplyr)

test <- test %>% group_by(Instrument) %>%
  mutate(
      p_pbt_situtation_sum = sum(p_pbt_situation == "rising_payout_falling_profit", 
                                 na.rm=TRUE)
  )
```

and then use this new column in `case_when()`:

```
test %>% 
  mutate(
      Ratchet_occurrence = 
case_when(
    p_pbt_situtation_sum== 0 & has_ever_payout==1 ~"never",
    p_pbt_situtation_sum == 1 ~"once",
    p_pbt_situtation_sum == 2 ~ "twice",
    p_pbt_situtation_sum >2 & p_pbt_situtation_sum < 5   ~ "three or four",
    p_pbt_situtation_sum >4 & p_pbt_situtation_sum < 7   ~ "five or six",
    p_pbt_situtation_sum >6   ~ "seven or more",
    has_ever_payout == 0 ~ "no payout",
     TRUE ~ NA_character_
)) %>% ungroup()
```

This way, you calculate the sum only once per group instead of eight times. Next, you could also change the order of your formulas in `case_when()` into their frequency. `case_when()` will stop after the first epression evaluates to TRUE, so by having the most common TRUE expression first, you save a lot of unneccessary expression evaluated to FALSE.